# Connect and create a local Oracle database

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I've installed sqlplus64 throw this tutorial: http://webikon.com/cases/installing-oracle-sql-plus-client-on-ubuntu

I want to practice SQL using sqlplus (I can't connect remotely to school ssh).

I've tried everything I found in google and still can't connect.
I don't have any credentials

```
sqlplus64 / as sysdba
```

ERROR:

> ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Comment: Do you have a server to connect to?

Comment: `sqlplus` is a **client** software that connects to an existing (and running) Oracle database server. You have to also install an Oracle database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

Probably the easiest way to get started with SQL using sqlplus is to use the virtual machine image Oracle provides for the hands on lab. It contains not only sqlplus, but a full Oracle 12c database, already configured correctly.

Download and instructions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html). It's free. You'll need a free account on OTN (Oracle Technology Network), but that's necessary anyway to read the documentation about SQL*Plus and all the rest of it.